# Convert NSDate from GMT+0 (London) to User's TimeZone

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I have a NSString (date) retrieved from my MySQL database which is in GMT +000 (London) and its format is like this: 12/05/2011 5:21:29 PM.

I would like to know how I could convert it to the user's time zone so that if the user was in china for example, it would be that date in the chinese time zone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `setTimeZone:` on your input `NSDateFormatter`. (Internally, `NSDate`s are time zone agnostic.)

E.g.:

```
// The default time zone for a formatter is the time zone of the user's locale
NSDateFormatter *localFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[localFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[localFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

NSDateFormatter *gmtFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[gmtFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a"];
[gmtFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

NSDate *date = [gmtFormatter dateFromString:gmtDateString];
NSString *locallyFormattedDate = [localFormatter stringFromDate:date];

[localFormatter release];
[gmtFormatter release];
```

Although…I don't think this takes DST into account if the DST setting during the specified time is different than the current setting.

Comment: `gmtDateString` is undefined.

Comment: gmtDateString is meant to be your GMT date string. ;)

Answer (score -2):

Use `initWithTimeInterval:sinceDate:` to make a date object that adds/subtracts hours. It will be in seconds, so 3 hours ahead would be initWithTimeInterval:10800 sinceDate:(originalDate). The format that would be given if you called `-description` on that object would be given as (from Apple Documentation)

> A string representation of the
>   receiver in the international format
>   YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS ±HHMM, where ±HHMM
>   represents the time zone offset in
>   hours and minutes from GMT (for
>   example, “2001-03-24 10:45:32 +0600”).

So it would include the time interval.

EDIT:
Sorry I was using the wrong init method, that is the one you are looking for, initWithTimeInterval:sinceDate:. You make a new NSDate that adds or subtracts the number of seconds that the timezone is ahead/behind.

Comment: I don't understand how I could convert the date between the time-zones.

Comment: I edited my answer to use the right method, initWithTimeInterval:SinceDate.

Comment: so do I need to know the offset for every single timezone?

Comment: No, you can use `-[NSTimeZone secondsFromGMT]` or `-[NSTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:]`.