# how to convert indian time into London time

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nstimezone

how to convert india time into UK time programmatically?
Example : india time : 1.30
Convert in to UK time : 9.00

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Time will be same wether it is Indian or UK. You need to format it using NSDateFormatter with the appropriate time zone info.

Comment: i dont have any idea can you tell me how can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a";
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
NSString *strTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"strTime :%@",strTime);
```

Comment: thx buddy its work fine but can you tell me it is only working for UK? and what we will do for other country ?

Comment: @user3140414, click the checkmark to accept this answer. As far as converting to other time zones, you just need to change the line that assigns the timeZone to use the desired target time zone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use setTimeZone method of NSDateFormatter.
Please check this:
[Convert NSDate from GMT+0 (London) to User's TimeZone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165247/convert-nsdate-from-gmt0-london-to-users-timezone)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to get it:

```
   //First get second from GMT
    NSTimeInterval timeZoneOffset = [[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];//Here you can use TimeZone as per your requirement 
   //Get time difference 
    NSTimeInterval gmtTimeInterval = [your_date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - timeZoneOffset;
    //Finally get your date
    NSDate *timeZoneDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:gmtTimeInterval];
```